# How to get a response(audio file) of an API endpoint to a flutter application?

Tags: flutter, dart, rest

In flutter app, I'm capturing an image and send to the python API. There it gives the audio output file as the response. I want to get that response audio file to my flutter app to display in the UI and to download it.

[image: Postman response (audio file)]

This what I have tried so far.

```
    void _choose() async {
    File file;
    file = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
    );
    if (file != null) {
      var haveImg = true;
      var futureImg = _uploadFile(file);
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  final String endPoint = 'http://192.168.1.10:5000/image';
 

  void _uploadFile(File file) async {
    String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;
    print(fileName);

    FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
      "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
        file.path,
        filename: fileName,
      ),
    });



    Dio dio = new Dio();

    var response = await dio.post(endPoint, data: data);

  }
```

As mention above, now I want to implement a get request to get the audio and display it in the Ui. So how to achieve this?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
response = await dio.download("https://www.example.com/image.png");
```